# How to hide subdirectory from url without affecting index page of root directory

Tags: .htaccess

can anyone please me How to hide subdirectory from url in php using htaccess without affecting index page of root directory

suppose i have url https://evidhya.com/KSTA-Webinar i want to hide KSTA-Webinar subdirectory from url but it should not affect index page of the https://evidhya.com and i just want to display in url https://evidhya.com/-KSTA-Webinar and here -KSTA-Webinar is title of the page

Answer (score 2):

I tried myself and found the answer it is working perfectly for me.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^-KSTA-Webinar/?$ KSTA-Webinar/-KSTA-Webinar [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you only want `-KSTA-Webinar` to redirect to the real folder `KSTA-Webinar`? If so, you can just change your `<a href='...'` values to include the `-`, then add this to your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^-KSTA-Webinar$ KSTA-Webinar/index.php [L]
```

...or whatever your file path is

Comment: Hi CssStuck KSTA-Webinar is different it is a subdirectory name and -KSTA-Webinar is different it is a title name which is coming from database both are not same.